# angular 6 pwa does not work

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, angular6, angular-service-worker

I did a simple

```
ng new cx --service-worker
cd cx
```

First observation: i do not see service worker installed using this in package.json or any module entry etc. is it a bug?

I moved on and used

```
ng add @angular/pwa
```

This adds the service worker. However, on running it i see the error in the console:

```
Manifest.json

Unexpected error line 1 col 1, unexpected token;
```

**mnifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "cx",
  "short_name": "cxa",
  "theme_color": "#1976d2",
  "background_color": "#fafafa",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```

I verified that the file does exist in src/ location with non empty contents. i kept those default for now.

```
ng -v 
Angular CLI: 6.0.1
Node: 8.11.1
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 6.0.2
```

Comment: Can you post your `manifest.json` code?

Comment: i just added it pradeep

Comment: How are you running the server when you test this? Your error mentions `Manifest.json` with a capital `M`, does the capitalization of the actual manifest file, the network request for the manifest file, and the `link` tag in `index.html` all consistently cased?

Comment: Start over and follow these steps: 
https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I had an application started, but then wanted to add `@angular/cli` to the project afterwards. Nothing worked though I compared it to https://github.com/ng-model/pwa/. I notice that they did not do the same as I do below.

I ended up adding the following to the end of my `index.html`:

```
<script>
  if ( 'serviceWorker' in navigator ) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js');
    });
  }
</script>
```

For Angular 6+, the file name changed to `ngsw-worker.js`

```
<script>
  if ( 'serviceWorker' in navigator ) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('/ngsw-worker.js');
    });
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to run below command in your angular project.

ng add @angular/pwa --project *project-name*

, where *project-name* Is a name you already defined in your angular.json file.

The above command will do following code change in your angular project out of the box. **YOU DO NOT NEED TO ANYTHING ELSE.**

Enables service worker build support in the CLI by installing related packages (‘@angular/pwa’ and ‘@angular/service-worker’). It also add those package in package.json file.

2. Add following lines in index.html
3. Add following line in app.module imports.

ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: true })

4. Create manifes.webmanifest file is src folder
5. Create service worker configuration file called  ngsw-config.json file in root folder
6. Update angular.json file with following changes in configuration object.

"configuration":  {

```
"production": {

    "serviceWorker": true,

     "ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"

}
```

}

7. Installs icon files to support the installed Progressive Web App (PWA).

Read about PWA in Angular and how to debug it [here](https://blogpedia.org/blogs/321/convert-your-angular-application-to-pwaprogressive-web-application-through-service-workers)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't updated to Angular 6 myself. But here are some links that might be helpful in resolving errors and configuring manifest.json.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-progressive-web-apps-with-angular
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/

Comment: yeah checked those, ideally the steps are pretty basic and my first app should run as is, but sadly it does not

Comment: @AdiMabfalin The question is not about Angular JS, it's about Angular.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run Chrome Dev tools -> Audit -> Perform an Audit -> Progressive Web App and give us that screenshot, without which its just a black box on what all [PWA criteria](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/) are met and what's not.

Report should be explicit in whats the issue with your PWA and help you solve the issue. If not, please post the screenshot and we'll help further on it.

Comment: here u https://www.dropbox.com/s/0wz0e3cjarnok9n/Screen%20Shot%202018-05-17%20at%2011.32.26%20AM.png?dl=0 i have tried lighthouse multiple time but it fails. and i think the reason is as page fails to render it self. which is default as created by owa aoo

Comment: What do you mean by 'owa aoo'? Its so clear your manifest.json is not served correctly and possibly you are accessing in HTTP instead of HTTPS.  If what you have is a simple default project created with Angular CLI, go ahead and post the code in github and link here. Also make sure, you are not running the app using ng serve as it wont support PWA. You have to use something like http-server -o -i <IP> -p <port> -S to support your web app in HTTPS to access as PWA.

Comment: typo owa aoo is actually pwa app :)

Answer (score 0):

For me the fix was within IIS.  I had to add a mime type to handle the manifest.webmanifest file.

File Extenstion:

```
.webmanifest
```

MIME Type:

```
application/manifest+json
```